# Lebesgue Integral expected value derivation

Tags: probability, lebesgue-integral, expectation

The expected value can be defined in the following 2 ways

$$
E(x)=\int x.f(x) dx
$$
$$
E(x)=\int_0^1 x dF(x) 
$$
I have an intuitive understanding of both of them.
The first I can visualize moving along the x axis and multiplying x by some weight which is very small for most values. Where it is not so small, those values of x have a higher representation in the total sum.
The second I can visualize moving along the y axis, pausing at infinitesimal regular intervals and noting the value of x where my current y value intersects. I will encounter similar values of x when the slope of the function is very steep and so those values will have a higher representation in the total sum.

How do I show, analytically, that these 2 function are equivalent?

Comment: is $dF = fdx$ enough to convince you? (assuming your random variable is nice enough for this to hold...)

Comment: It certainly helps to bear that in mind. The bit that I am struggling with is that we were integrating over the real line. Now we are integrating from 0 to 1. I know why, but that is only because I have an intuitive understanding of the problem. What is the general rule here?

Comment: @Travis, the procedure is [Integration By Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) other wise known as Change of Variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure is [Integration By Substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) other wise known as Change of Variable.

Since $F:\Bbb R\to [0;1]$ we must change the interval to correspond when we change the variable of integration using $y=F(x)$, $x=F^{-1}(y)$ , and $\frac{\operatorname d F(x)}{\operatorname d x}\operatorname d x = \operatorname d y$ .

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) & = \int_\Bbb R x\;f(x)\operatorname d x \\[1ex] & = \int_\Bbb R x\;\frac{\operatorname d F(x)}{\operatorname d x}\operatorname d x \\[1ex] & =\int_0^1 F^{-1}(y)\operatorname d y  \end{align}$$

> (assuming your random variable is nice enough for this to hold...) –  Calvin Khor

Comment: Are you sure you did that right? Did you leave out an x on the last line? why did you change integrating over the real line to integrating from 0 to 1?

Comment: @Travis Since $F:\Bbb R\to [0;1]$ we must change the interval to correspond when we change the variable of integration using $y=F(x)$, $x=F^{-1}(y)$ , and $\frac{\operatorname d F(x)}{\operatorname d x}\operatorname d x = \operatorname d y$ .